# When to use getparent()

Tags: android

In my custom view I need to use the getParent method and set the visibility on some of it's child views depending on my custom view's state. The problem is that I want to instantiate the child views just once. Where is the best place to do this?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not exactly sure what you want to do. But if all of this is occurring in the same Activity screen why don't you just assign `id`s (e.g. `android:id="@+id/someId"` to your elements in the `layout.xml` file.

This way you can reference any element programatically in your code by calling:

```
View someView = findViewById(R.id.someId);
```

I am unclear why you would need to call `getParent`. If you are trying to manipulate views in a **different** activity then I think you will need to use a `Handler`.